# How can I look at whether different groups are succeeding more often than chance?

Tags: logistic, mixed-model, random-variable

I am doing an analysis and want to be sure I'm going about it in the correct way. I'm not going to give real examples, but will just make up variables.

Let's say each participant answers 100 trivia questions in a random order. These trivia questions come from five categories (20 each). I want to know if people tend to get more answers correct than chance from any of the five categories. I ultimately don't care about comparing the categories to each other.

So I run an overall mixed effects logistic regression model like this:

`m <- glmer(Acuracy ~ Category + (1|Participant) + (1|Item))`

I use whatever test has an accuracy closest to chance as the reference level.

Then I use emmeans to separately compare accuracy in each Category to chance.

`emms <- emmeans(m, "Category")`

`test(emms, null = 0)`

Does this look right?

Edit: Here is an example that is closer to my real data.

I'm going to make up an experiment here. It will be a silly example that approximates my situation.

- Lets say participants get two colours to choose between. One is always a type of red, one is always a type of blue.
- They get 100 trials. On each trial, they get a word associated with one of the four seasons (e.g., snow, Christmas, cold for winter).
- They task is to choose which of the two colours (the shade of red/or the shade of blue) is the best match for that word.

What I want to know is if red or blue are chosen more often than chance for words from any of the four seasons individually. In other words, is red chosen more often for summer words, for fall words, for winter words and for sprint words. Four separate questions.

This is how I am going about analyzing the data.

First building an overall mixed effects logistic regression model. Season is dummy coded, with the one closest to chance as the reference level.

`m <- glmer(ChoseRed ~ Season + (1|Participant) + (1|Word), family = "binomial")`

Then I use emmeans to compare choices during each season to chance.

```
emms <- emmeans(m_final, "Factor")
test(emms, null = 0)
```

Does this make sense?

Comment: If this even works, it looks like overkill, because you are really asking for a basic probability calculation: namely, to describe the Binomial distribution and compare the results in each category to the probabilities it gives.

Comment: @whuber Can you explain why it wouldn't work? And what you are suggesting is running separate models for each Category and just interpreting the intercepts?

Comment: You don't need separate models and you need very little calculation, because the hypothesis of chance responses determines, solely through the axioms of probability, what distribution of results you would see in each category.  All you have to do is compare what you observe to that distribution. Although I don't know what `emmeans` will do -- I don't use it -- it's implausible that a hypothesis expressed as `null=0` is correctly implementing your question.  For instance, what would it output if people were randomly answering in four categories but in the fifth always chose *incorrect* answers?

Comment: @whuber I changed my example in an edit, see if you still feel the same way.